# Making POST on 'refresh' permamently deregisters the service from Eureka

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I started playing around spring-cloud-config-server. I am using **Dalston.RELEASE**. 
Everything works fine but when I do **/refresh** on config-client then properties are refreshed but it is no longer recognized by EUREKA server.


Similar issue:-

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/421

The client is not registering itself aslso as Eureka client.

How can I resolve this or this is a known bug?
**Config Server- application.yml**

```
server:
 port: 8888 

spring:
profiles:
active:
  - native
config:
  name: configuration
cloud:
 config:
  server:
    native:
      search-locations: file:///home/properties

  uri: http://localhost:8889     
  application:
 name : configuration
eureka:
 client:
  service-url:
    defaultZone: http://localhost:19880/eureka/
```

And Config-client-application.yml

```
spring:
application:
 name: services  
 cloud:
   config:
     uri: http://localhost:8888
     enabled: true
```

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1857 a fix has been made

Comment: @spencergibb... so when this will be released to production? I am using Dalston.RELEASE having 1.5.3.RELEASE as spring cloud dependecy.